# Difference between $q.when and $q.defer in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angular-promise

I am seeing angularJS files where in some places reviewer has commented these 3 lines:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
deferred.resolve(BrandList);
return deferred.promise;
```

and replaced with this one:

```
return $q.when(BrandList);
```

I would like to understand the difference between two. Do both serve same purpose? Which should be used when?

Comment: Yes, they do the same. But only the second conveys the intent (and it's shorter as well).

Comment: So can we use either of two at any point of time in our code??

Comment: Well, `$q.when` is a single function, and could be passed around. A call to it makes a single expression that can be used about everywhere, while the first snippet with `$q.defer()` contains multiple statements.

Answer (score 4):

Ben Nadal does a great job of explaining this [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2735-q-when-is-the-missing-q-resolve-method-in-angularjs.htm).

In his words:

> The $q.when() method doesn't just create a promise that is immediately resolved; rather, it normalizes a value that may or may not be a "thenable" object. If the given value is a promise, $q.when() will properly chain off of it. If the given value is not a promise, $q.when() will create promise resolved with the given value.

So essentially it takes either promises or non-promises and does some magic to make sure they are either resolved or promise wrapped so as not to break the promise chain.

Answer (score 1):

`$q.defer()` is appropriate when you want to decorate a function to use promises instead of callbacks. Usually, you will specify a `deferred.resolve()` and a `deferred.reject()`, and maybe even a `deferred.notify()`.

`$q.when()` is appropriate when you want to immediately create a new promise and resolve it to a value. **EDIT** it also normalizes variables into promises, which is useful if the variable may or may not be a promise. See Jim's answer.

`$q.when()` seems to be appropriate for your case.